# Debugging GWT client side with IntelliJ12 JBOSS server

Tags: gwt, jboss, intellij-idea

I try to set up 'GWT configuration' in IntelliJ 12. I am using JBoss as my server.

My project contains GWT client side code which talks to a set of java services. I been up and running with this project smoothly. Now, I need to debug a client side issue and I try to do it following below steps.

1. From IntelliJIdea add a new GWT configuration. In the DevMode parameters I give below.

   `-noserver -war "D:/code/myproject/target/myproject -startupUrl http://localhost:8080/myproject"`

   [image]
2. Launch the debug configuration.

I am getting below in the console

```
Dev Mode initialized. Startup URL: 
http://127.0.0.1:8888/Application.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

But when I access the page using that URL I get a blank page.

Does any body have experience with configuring GWT debugging with IntelliJ with JBOSS?

Probably I may have missed out an argument in the dev mode parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. I haven't add my module name at the end of the DevMode parameters.

So I added 
`-noserver -war "D:/code/myproject/target/myproject -startupUrl http://localhost:8080/myproject org.myproject.ui`

After I added that every thing was working fine. After increasing the VM options to 
`-Xmx1024m` instead of initial `-Xmx256m` the page loaded much faster.